# Can I convert doc to docx, ppt to pptx, xls to xlsx and vice versa with okapi and java?

Tags: java, file-conversion, xliff

I'd like to ask can I convert MS-office files using java and okapi? 
Such as doc to docx, ppt to pptx, xls to xlsx and vice versa.
Maybe convert the file to xliff and then convert the xliff to the required format?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No.

[OKAPI Supported File Formats](http://okapiframework.org/wiki/index.php?title=Filters#Supported_File_Formats)

Per the documentation, Okapi supports MS-Office OpenXML formats (like .docx and .xlsx), but it is NOT intended to convert between legacy MS-Office formats and OpenXML:

Between OpenXML and OpenOffice, or Doxygen, or many, many other document formats - yes.  Interconvert MS-Office formats: no.

SUGGESTION:

You might wish to consider purchasing commercial libraries, such as Aspose:

http://www.aspose.com/products/words/java

Comment: Thank you. Aspose is useful to word file transformation, but not free.

Comment: And I'm using poi to convert ppt and xls to pptx and xlsx now.